# how to find this solution for Error : object with reference: product_id - product.id?

Tags: python, odoo-8, openerp-8

i want create stock move , and this my code

```
class Selection(models.Model):
    """Seed Selection"""
    _name = 'estate.nursery.selection'
    _inherits = {'stock.production.lot': 'lots_id'}
    picking_id= fields.Many2one('stock.picking', "Picking", readonly=True)
    lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', "Lot",required=True, ondelete="restrict", domain=[('product_id.seed','=',True)])
    selectionline_ids = fields.One2many('estate.nursery.selectionline', 'selection_id', "Selection Lines")
    batch_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.batch', "Batch")
    stage_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.stage',"Stage")
    selectionstage_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.selectionstage',"Selection Stage")
    qty_normal = fields.Integer("Normal Seed Quantity",)
    qty_abnormal = fields.Integer("Abnormal Seed Quantity",)
    date_planted = fields.Date("Planted Date",required=False,readonly=False)
    qty_batch = fields.Integer("DO Quantity",required=False,readonly=True)
    presentage_normal = fields.Float("Persentage Normal",digits=(2,2),required=False)
    presentage_abnormal = fields.Float("Persentage Abnormal",digits=(2,2), required=False)
    date = fields.Date("Selection Date",required=True)
    selection_type = fields.Selection([('0', 'Broken'),('1', 'Normal'),('2', 'Politonne')], "Selection Type")
    comment = fields.Text("Additional Information")
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', "Product", related="lots_id.product_id")
    nursery_stage = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('0', '(PN)'),
        ('1', '(MN)'),
        ('done', 'Done')], default='draft', string="Selection Stage")
    nursery_information = fields.Selection([('draft','Draft'),('0','untimely'),('1','late'),('2','passed')], default='draft', string="Information Time" , readonly=True,required=False)
    nursery_lapsetime = fields.Integer(string="Information Lapse of Time",required=False,readonly=True,compute='calculatedays',multi='sums',store=True)

    state = fields.Selection(SESSION_STATES,string='Status',required=True,readonly=True,)
    _defaults = {
        'state' :  SESSION_STATES[0][0]
    }

    #onchange value
    @api.onchange('batch_id')
    def date_change(self):
        self.date_planted=self.batch_id.date_planted
        self.qty_batch=self.batch_id.qty_received

    #workflow state
    @api.one
    @api.depends('state')
    def action_draft(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        return self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'state' : SESSION_STATES[0][0]},context=None)
    def action_confirmed(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        return self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'state' : SESSION_STATES[1][0]},context=None)
    def action_done(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        return self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'state' : SESSION_STATES[2][0]},context=None)
    def action_receive(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        normal = self.qty_normal
        abnormal = self.qty_abnormal
        selectionlineids = self.selectionline_ids
        for item in selectionlineids:
            normal += normal
            abnormal += abnormal
        self.write({'qty_normal': self.qty_normal, 'qty_abnormal': self.qty_abnormal})

        self.action_move()
        return self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'state' : SESSION_STATES[3][0]},context=None)
    @api.one
    def action_move(self):
        location_ids = set()
        for item in self.selectionline_ids:
            if item.location_id and item.qty_planted > 0: # todo do not include empty quantity location
                location_ids.add(item.location_id)

        for location in location_ids:
            qty_batch= 0
            bedeng = self.env['estate.nursery.selectionline'].search([('location_id', '=', location.id),
                                                                   ('selection_id', '=', self.id)])
            for i in bedeng:
                qty_batch += i.qty_batch

            move_data = {
                'product_id': self.lots_id.product_id.id,
                'product_uom_qty': qty_batch,
                'product_uom': self.lots_id.product_id.uom_id.id,
                'date_expected': self.date_planted,
                'location_id': self.picking_id.location_dest_id.id,
                'location_dest_id': location.id,
                'state': 'confirmed', # set to done if no approval required
                'restrict_lot_id': self.lots_id.id # required by check tracking product
            }

            move = self.env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
            move.action_confirm()
            move.action_done()
```

And my error:

- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: product_id - product.id]

Comment: Please correct your question's formatting.

Comment: clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Check your calls to the create methods and their models.

It must be a required field you are not giving to these create methods (or may be you are giving it with value `False`).

It's important that you check the models (not the database tables or the XML views) because it could be a required field in the model which is not in the view or with `store=False`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem,

```
self.lots_id.product_id.id
```

you should write like this,

```
self.lots_id and self.lots_id.product_id and self.lots_id.product_id.id or False
```

Prepare your move_data in that way so you will never get this kind of errors, every time you need to check the possibility of None(none reference) value for referential fields.

```
move_data = {
                self.lots_id and self.lots_id.product_id and self.lots_id.product_id.id or False,
                ### Add all others
            }
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1415, in _dispatch_nodb
    func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()
 that my new error :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1430, in match
    raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404: Not Found

Comment: and this my code :,  move_data = {
                'batch_id' : self.batch_id,
                'qty_batch' : self.qty_batch,
                'product_id': self.lots_id and self.lots_id.product_id and self.lots_id.product_id.id or False,
              
            }

Comment: this error doesn't stop your program execution, it's common issue ignore it